# Why do we need @Component spring annotation for Jersey resource in spring-boot-starter-jersey project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey, spring-annotations

This question is regarding the sample:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey/src/main/java/sample/jersey/Endpoint.java

Why do we need "@Component" annotation for Jersey resource when using spring-boot -starter-jersey project?

If I remove it, the Jersey servlet can still serve resources.

So what is the need for "@Component"?

Comment: As soon as you want to inject other Spring components, the resource has also to be a Spring component.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *need* it. Jersey uses [HK2](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b06/) as it's internal DI framework, and HK2 has a [Spring bridge](https://hk2.java.net/spring-bridge/). This is what's used internally to bridge Spring components into the HK2 IoC container, so that they can be injected into Jersey components. And Jersey implements an `AutowiredInjectionResolver`<sup>1</sup> that allows for injection of Spring components using `@Autowired`. You don't even need `@Autowired` though. All the Spring components can be injected with the normal `@Inject`.

The only drawback I've ran into, not making the Jersey components a Spring `@Component` is that it doesn't support `@Value` when you want to inject property values.

The one thing I *don't* like is that when you declare something a Spring `@Component`, it automatically makes it a singleton. But Jersey resources are by default request scoped. You can add a Spring `@Scope("request")`, and it should change the resource to a request scoped resource. Jersey has [declared the Spring RequestScope](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.23.1/ext/spring3/src/main/resources/jersey-spring-applicationContext.xml), so we can use it. How exactly it ties in to Jersey's request scope, I am not a hundred percent sure. I ran into a problem a while back. I can't remember what it was, but that has kept me from ever using the Spring request scope again.

Assuming I want to keep all my resources request scoped, I would take sticking to the normal Jersey request scope, and not being able to inject `@Value`s, over having to use Spring's request scope. Maybe I'm imagining things, and there *was* no issue using it, but personally I'll just stick to what I know works :-)

### UPDATE

Another thing that does't work if you don't make the resource a Spring `@Component` is Spring's AOP. That's fine with me though as HK2 also has AOP.

---

<sub>1 - An [InjectionResolver](https://hk2.java.net/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/InjectionResolver.html) allows you to use custom annotations to create injection targets.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

When you remove @Component jersey takes control of the scope of the instance. With @Component a singleton instance is created, removing it you can use the following jersey annotations:

• Request scope (Default):
By using the @RequestScope annotation or none, we can have a life-cycle till
the request lasts. This is the default scope of the root-resource classes. For
each new request, a new root-resource instance is being created and served
accordingly for the first time. However, when the same root-resource method
is being called, then the old instance will be used to serve the request.

• Per-lookup scope:
The @PerLookup annotation creates root-resource instances for every request.

• Singleton:
The @Singleton annotation allows us to create only a single instance
throughout the application.

---

Try different behaviors using a counter inside your class...

```
public class MyWebResource {
private int counter;

@GET
@Path("/counter")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getCounter() {
    counter++;
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(counter).build();
}

}
```